# Conditional IF/ELSE Statement in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was trying to make a simple statement with Matlab as follows:

```
if TF==1
  disp('One'), break
else continue
end
... ... ...
... ... ...
```

But even if TF is not 1, when I run the command, it doesn't CONTINUE to the rest of the script!! Any help would be appreciated-- Thanks

Comment: No need for that `else continue`, just remove that line.

Comment: Is this 'if' inside a loop? The continue statement would actually discard the present iteration and start a fresh one. It will not proceed after the line of code its present in. Break would exit the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `continue` statement has a very different meaning. Within a loop, like a `for` or `while` loop, `continue` instructs to skip the current round and *continue* with the next iteration in the loop. So if you remove `continue`, you will see the behavior that you are expecting. Here is an example:

```
for k = 1 : 10
  if k == 4
    % skip the calculation in the case where k is 4
    continue
  end
  area = k * k;
  disp(area);
end
```

When the loop iterates at `k == 4`, the block calculating the area of the corresponding square is skipped. This particular example is not very practical.

However, imagine you have a list of ten file names, and you want to process each file in this loop "`for k = 1 : 10`". You will have to try and open each file, but then if you find out the file does not exist, an appropriate way to handle it would be to print a little warning and then `continue` to the next file.

Comment: and `break` is also intended to be used in a loop: it quits the loop altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much, I miscomprehended 'continue'